# Unable to connect to mysql in Istio environment

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We have configured the Kubernetes cluster on bare-metal server with v1.15.1 and Istio-1.4.0 (demo) with mTLS enabled. 
And our mysql server is outside the K8s cluster on Azure VM's.
Now when we inject istio-proxy while deploying the application we are unable to connect to mysql server via jdbc and also tried my mysql client. But when remove the istio-proxy by re-deploying we are able to connect instantly with out any issue.

When through many blogs wrt istio and mysql, tried with removing the default mesh policy but tht didnt work. The case in istio faq's is when the mysql is in k8s cluster with istio injected.

Comment: Look into adding a ServiceEntry for the external MySQL (see [this post here](https://istio.io/blog/2018/egress-tcp/#mesh-external-service-entry-for-an-external-mysql-instance)).

Comment: Hi, like @char mentioned using `ServiceEntry` is simpler solution rather than making `mysql` connection `mTLS` friendly. However i suggest using current [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) example instead. The blog post from 2018 might be outdated. What istio version do You have?

Comment: try also setting `values.global.mtls.auto=true` this will use mtls only when possible

Comment: @char .. we tried with ServiceEntry. First we created a service and endpoint for our mysql server and the added the serviceentry and destinationrule (tls disabled)

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi .. I have already installed the istio-1.4.0 with demo profile, how can i add this settings, As i can see mTLS is by default enabled with mesh policy and

Comment: reinstall istio with the option enabled

Comment: @AnkitSaxena: Use `istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo \
  --set values.global.mtls.auto=true` to enable the setting talked about. 
Have you tried it with just a ServiceEntry, without a DestinationRule and restarting the pods after adding everything?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure auto-mtls for istio  by configuring `values.global.mtls.auto=true` (ie it uses mtls when possible and falls back for other connections

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authentication/auto-mtls/

Answer (score 0):

Serviceentry and destionation rule does the work form my case